# How to order Test Scenarios in specflow using nunit3console

Tags: c#, integration-testing, specflow, nunit-console

How can I order my scenarios to run in a given order?

I have a series of scenarios that depend on the previous scenario having run.

I'm running my specflow tests using nunit3console.

I haven't found anything online that seems to work.

And yes my tests do need to run in a particular order otherwise it's pointless.

Scenario: I perform first scenario

Scenario: I perform second scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NUnit by default runs tests in alphabhetical order. As of NUnit 3 you can try running these in order, reference [here](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Order-Attribute).

It is not considered good practice to limit scenarios to run in a particular order though as each and every one of them sould be able to run independently of one another.

Other posts with similar information, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943099/is-there-a-way-to-run-specflow-scenarios-in-desired-order-c-selenium) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921332/what-is-the-order-of-execution-in-nunit/921339).

Comment: I mean in theory except if I require something to have happened in a organized workflow I do want things to run in a particular order.  Unless specflow and nunit aren't the tools I should use for my testing and there's something else out there or I have to abandon nunit and specflow and create a custom application to run a series of documented tests...?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you want achieve by having tests ordered in a particular way. You could also sort the ordering in your reporting system after all tests have run in theory too (if you want to present your tests in a particular, customized way to business, for example).